# Enable a single selection between 2 Lists

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I am encountering this problem, and I hope someone can help me.

I am trying to create a situation where there are 2 QListWidgets, `List01` and `List02` for example, and they contains the following.

```
List01 = [T01, T02, T03]
List02 = [P01, P02, P03]
```

I wanted the user to select an item `(T01)` in `List01`, and hence in `List02`, no selection (highlighting) of any items will be conducted, meaning to say if the user hovers over to `List02` and selects an item `(P02)`, the selection in `List01` will be gone and it will be the item `(P02)` selected in `List02`.

Currently, I am getting the problem, where my program is able to select an item in the 2 lists and I am not sure how to perform the above.

Could someone kindly guide me?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post an example code?

Comment: Erm, the thing is I do not have the code as I was totally lost in how to do it in the first place... The only code thus far I have, is the code for my 2 lists where they are localDir = os.listdir("/Desktop/Proj") and self.jobList.addItems(localDir) 
It is the same coding for the other list as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is an example code of how could you do what you want, it's very basic but you can get the idea within the functions `f` and `g`, hope it works:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui


app = gui.QApplication([]) 


w = gui.QWidget()
l = gui.QHBoxLayout(w)
w.setLayout(l)

lis1 = gui.QListWidget()
lis2 = gui.QListWidget()

lis1.addItems(["1","2","3"])
lis2.addItems(["4","5","6"])

def f():    
    lis2.itemSelectionChanged.disconnect(g)    
    for item in lis2.selectedItems():
        lis2.setItemSelected(item,False)
    lis2.itemSelectionChanged.connect(g)


def g():
    lis1.itemSelectionChanged.disconnect(f)    
    for item in lis1.selectedItems():
        lis1.setItemSelected(item,False)    
    lis1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(f)


print dir(lis1.itemSelectionChanged)

lis1.itemSelectionChanged.connect(f)
lis2.itemSelectionChanged.connect(g)

l.addWidget(lis1)
l.addWidget(lis2)

w.show()


app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hi xndrme, thanks for the example. I will try it as soon as possible to see how it goes once I'm back to school and see how it goes. By the way, can I ask what does 'disconnect(g)' means? Is it, disconnect the def g()?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the `itemSelectionChanged()` signal from one `QListWidget` to the `clearSelection` slot of the other.

Example generated with QtDesigner:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(214, 158)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setText("T01")
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setText("T02")
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setText("T03")
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.listWidget_2 = QtGui.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setText("P01")
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setText("P02")
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setText("P03")
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        # This are the important lines.
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemSelectionChanged()"), self.listWidget_2.clearSelection)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listWidget_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemSelectionChanged()"), self.listWidget.clearSelection)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take example on this code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MyApp(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyApp, self).__init__()

    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    qlist1 = QtGui.QListWidget()
    qlist1.addItems(["elem1","elem2","elem3"])
    layout.addWidget(qlist1)

    qlist2 = QtGui.QListWidget()
    qlist2.addItems(["elem4","elem5","elem6"])
    layout.addWidget(qlist2)

    # This dict will be used when a list is clicked
    # to clear the selection of the other list
    self.list_dict = {}
    self.list_dict[qlist1] = qlist2
    self.list_dict[qlist2] = qlist1

    qlist1.clicked.connect(self.list_clicked)
    qlist2.clicked.connect(self.list_clicked)

    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.show()

  def list_clicked(self):
    self.list_dict[self.sender()].clearSelection()

myApp = MyApp()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```